# Unsolved errors after installing Eclipse Neon2, buidlship, Gluon for Android applications

Tags: eclipse-plugin, bundle, eclipse-neon, gluon-mobile, springsource

I have installed, I think, all useful components that allow to develop some JavaFX applications dedicated to Android, with Eclipse Neon2

At this time, I can generate with this set of tools, from a Java(fx) project, an apk file for Android phone.

---

The configuration is:
- Eclipse Neon2 (4.6.2)
- Maven Aether Provider Bundle 3.1.0
- Eclipse Buildship 2.0.0
- Eclipse Code recommenders Mylyn , snipmatch and UI: 2.4.5
- Eclipse EGit, JGit 4.4.1
- Eclipse MarketPlace Client 1.5.3
- Eclipse Modeling Project 2.12.0
- Eclipse Mylyn 1.13.0 and 3.21.0
- Eclipse Oomph 1.6.0
- Eclipse Packaging project 4.6.2
- Eclipse Web Tools Platform 3.8.0
- Eclipse.org JDT 3.12.2
- Eclipse.org Platform, RCP 4.6.2
- Eclipse.org Help System Base 2.2.1
- Eclipse.org m2e 1.7.0
- Android Open Source Project (ADT, Dalvik, ...) 23.0.7

---

Question 1:

But some "residual" errors alway exist, as follows:

- error loading hook: org.eclipse.fx.osgi.fxloader.FXClassLoadingConfigurator
  org.eclipse.fx.osgi.fxloader.FXClassLoadingConfigurator
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/HookConfigurator
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookConfigurator
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
- org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
  Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: **bundleclass**://org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui/org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui.internal.handlers.MarkDuplicateElementIdsHandler
  ResetToDefaultHandler, MarkDuplicateLabelsHandler, ...
- in org.eclipse.core.runtime:
  Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.pde.ui/$nl$/icons/eview16/plugins.png
  java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.pde.ui/$nl$/icons/eview16/plugins.png".
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:61)
- in org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core:
  Could not load repository template extension contributed by 'org.**springsource**.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui' with connectorKind 'jira'
  An exception stack trace is not available.

Have you an idea for solving them?

---

Question2:

Moreover, I am not sure that my configuration was optimized (redundancy, ...).
If you have some ideas to minimize it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure why you are having so much troubles. Why don't you install fresh the latest Eclipse Mars (no need to remove other Eclipse installations), e(fx)clipse and the latest Gluon plugin for Eclipse? It should work "out of the box".

Comment: I had installed what you say. But, after installing Mars2, I got some trouble that avoid to correctly use its tools. Moreover, by reading it on the Web, Neon2 seemed to integrate better its hosted Tools. At the end, it is difficult, for me, to build again a good Eclipse-Gluon configuration...